# How to positioning the back of a Bootstrap flip card on the same position as the front?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need some help with a bootstrap flip card.
I try to create a Bootstrap flip card, but I cannot figure out how to get the back side on the same position as the front side. Can somebody help me please?

```css
.card-flip>div {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 300ms;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* margin: 0; */
  /* display: flex; */
}

.card-front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.card-flip:hover .card-front {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card-flip:hover .card-back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.11.0/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <strong>Header</strong>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<main style="min-height: calc(100vh - 111px); display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
  <div class="card-flip h-100">
    <div class="container my-5 z-depth-3 p-3 card-front">
      <h3 class="text-center display-4 mb-4">Front</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container my-5 z-depth-3 p-3 card-back">
      <h3 class="text-center display-4 mb-4">Back</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer class="page-footer text-center font-small black-text">
  <div class="py-1">
    Footer
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `position: relative` to `position: absolute` for `card-back` so it will stick on top of `card-front`.

```css
.card-flip {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
 }

.card-flip>div {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 300ms;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  /* margin: 0; */
  /* display: flex; */
}

.card-front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.card-back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.card-flip:hover .card-front {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card-flip:hover .card-back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.11.0/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
    <div class="navbar-brand">
      <strong>Header</strong>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<main style="min-height: calc(100vh - 111px); display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
  <div class="card-flip h-100">
    <div class="container my-5 z-depth-3 p-3 card-front">
      <h3 class="text-center display-4 mb-4">Front</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container my-5 z-depth-3 p-3 card-back">
      <h3 class="text-center display-4 mb-4">Back</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer class="page-footer text-center font-small black-text">
  <div class="py-1">
    Footer
  </div>
</footer>
```

**Edit** I've added `flex-box` properties to `card-flip`. So it'll set the position at the center.

Comment: This will not solve the problem. The back-card is under the front card :(

Comment: Now the cards are about each other :(

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand, I tested it on the code snippet and it worked.

Comment: Check the Code Snippet now. It works like a charm. :)